# WPF Can't Select Items in Datagrid after adding it to the ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid in my view that is bound to an ObservableCollection in my viewmodel, the issue that I am having is that after I programmtically add an a new Item to my ObservableCollection it appears in the Datagrid however I "Can and Cannot" select it, I know its a sounds a bit wacky but bear with me.
In code its somthing along the lines of:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList} SelectedValue{Binding Path=SelectedMyItem}... >
</Datagrid>
```

Then in my viewmodel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MyType> myList; 
 public ObservableCollection<MyType> MyList { get { return myList;} }

 privte void AddItem(MyType item)
 {
     myList.Add(item)
 }

public MyType SelectedMyItem {get;set;}
```

Now what happens is the Datarid gets updated and the new items appears in the grid. However when I try to select it, the grid highlights the previous item in the list, but the black border (that a selected item gets) appears around the new item. Aswell my SelectedValue Binding gets set to the new item. I have also created a context menu that allows user to delete items and when I right click and try to delete the newly added item, it instead  deletes the previous item in list.
However when this happens I am then able to properly select the new item. So I am guessing I need away to to refresh the datagrid I am assuming(note if I trigger INotifyPropertyChanged for MyList the sane thing still happens)

**EDIT:**

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var o = obj as MyType;
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        return o.MyTypeId == this.MyTypeId;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us `ARGReportGroup`, or `MyType`, which are presumably the same thing. Maybe you've overridden `Equals` and that is causing the `DataGrid` to be confused...guessing without code though.

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true

Comment: @KentBoogaart, Yea I did override Equals however I am just forcing it to check equals on the id instead. The id is an Int.

Comment: @Garry Vass I added IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true in alas it had no affect

Comment: @KentBoogaart Haha thanks I worked it out, it was getting confused. I simply missed something when I was adding in the a new group :/

Comment: Please mark the question as solved. I just read the entire thing just to see your last comment that you had solved it.